# Remove Lockbox encrypt from a column and generate another with the decrypted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a system made in Ruby on Rails that uses Lockbox in some columns. I need to remove the encrypt from them and generate another one with the data unencrypted. I can't lose the data.

I have very little knowledge of Ruby.

PS: Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could copy an encrypted column to a decrypted column (email column on a User model).

Add a migration to add a decrypted column

```
add_column :users, :decrypted_email, :string
```

Then write a rake task to fill in the decrypted column for each user

```
namespace :users do
  task :decrypt, [] => [:environment] do |t, args|
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.update_columns(decrypted_email: user.email)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The rake task must be saved in the ```lib/tasks``` folder within the rails project. And for those who need to run the rake, follow the command: ```bin/rake RAILS_ENV=development  rake_task_name```